# Unity 2018 script to make panel scroll up wont work if I go to the game scene before the credits scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, panel, coroutine

I am working on a game in Unity3D (what else would I be making) and so far I have the Main menu scene, the game scene and the Credits scene.

There is a script I made (shown below) That will make the panel holding the names scroll up that works fine if I select the credits scene from the main menu. But here is the problem. If I go to the game first and then go back to the main menu rand select credits nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollCredits : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Canvas;
    public int speed = 1;
    public string level;

private void Start()
{
    Canvas.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    StartCoroutine(waitFor());
}
private void Update()
{
}
IEnumerator waitFor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (69);
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `StartCoroutine` from `Update`? You only need one copy of that coroutine, not 2000.

Comment: @Draco18s I switched it to start and still the same problem.

Comment: "nothing happens" -> What does it means ? If you are not seeing the canvas, maybe it's because it is still going up and not on your menu anymore

Comment: @Eyap I mean the canvas and image shows up and the script is working when I look, but it is not making the credits scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You moved your Translate inside the `Start()`, it won't work that way.
Only `StartCoroutine` should be in `Start()`, like this :

```
public GameObject canvas;
public float speed = 0.1f;
public string sceneName;
public float timer;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitFor());
}

private void Update()
{
    canvas.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}

IEnumerator WaitFor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (timer);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}
```

Note : I changed `LoadLevel` to `SceneManager.LoadScene` because it's deprecated, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: This works PERFECTLY! Thank you so much. You saved me so much time.

Comment: Great ! You can accept this answer then, for completeness :)

Comment: For anyone here in the future. I found another glitch that would cause the script to not work. The fix is adding Time.timescale = 1; to start